# why wont this NSPredicate work?

Tags: iphone, core-data, static-libraries, nspredicate

i have a list of objects being managed by CoreData. i want to get a specific object out of CoreData using an NSPredicate. below is the code i am using. Array arr always comes back with 0 objects in it presumably because the fetch cant find an object that matches the predicate. i know for a fact that at least 1 object in CoreData has an advertisement.uuid that matches adUdid. i have manually gotten the entire list of objects and searched it myself for the uuid and found it. advertisement is a member of WebServiceAuthService_mobileAdvertisementVO and uuid is a member of advertisement. whats even more aggregating is the fact that this exact code works just fine in another project. im at a loss to figure out why this code no longer works in the new project.

incase it matters this code is in a static library i am making.

**EDIT:** arr is always empty so there is nothing to post. there are also no errors being given. its just not working. the uuids are NSStrings something along the lines of "9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d". i have a feeling the problem may be elsewhere in the code and just manifesting itself here.

```
WebServiceAuthService_mobileAdvertisementVO *mobileAd = nil;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WebServiceAuthService_mobileAdvertisementVO" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"advertisement.uuid == %@",adUdid];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *arr = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];

if (error) 
{
    DLog(@"fetched special ad error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

if (arr && [arr count] >= 1) 
{
    DLog(@"found ad with UUID %@",adUdid);
    for (WebServiceAuthService_mobileAdvertisementVO *obj in arr) 
    {
        NSManagedObjectID *objID = [obj objectID];
        if (![objID isTemporaryID]) 
        {
            mobileAd = obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried executing the fetch request without the predicate, presumably there are some objects of that entity in the store? Also, where does 'adUdid' come from? is it non-nil?

Comment: sorry about that Daniel adUdid is passed into this function and it is definitely no nil. and to answer you question after taking out the predicate the fetch returns 6 objects.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's a problem with the ==, as I use that to match against UUIDs in my code. Can you add to the question the output of the errors, (if there are any?), or just the output of 'arr', and finally can you give us an example of the advertisement.uuid, so the value and class, (we're presuming it's an NSString *).

Comment: what about case sensitivity?  Can you try using the `==[c]` operator in your predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings, in which case LIKE is a better operator than ==. So:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"advertisement.uuid LIKE %@",adUdid];
```

Don't worry about quotes, predicateWithFormat: will automatically put single quotes around the right hand term.

EDIT:
Reference: [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868)

Comment: nope this didn't work. what gets me is i have manually looked at the sqlite DB that CoreData makes and i can see the object with the UUID i am looking for.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow post a screenshot of your data model? It may be something silly like a missing letter somewhere, but it's impossible to say from the code.

Comment: the "LIKE" operator still needs to have the wildcard symbols in it.  Without `?` or `*` characters, you're still just doing an "equals" comparison.

Comment: @Dave De Long, sorry, but that is not the case. When comparing strings, whether in predicates, NSString or elsewhere, you cannot use 'equals' or == and expect sensible results. The NSPredicate Programming Guide section on String Comparisons specifies five operators: BEGINSWITH, CONTAINS, ENDSWITH, LIKE and MATCHES. Under LIKE it states: " ? and * are allowed as wildcard character". Allowed is not the same as required and using LIKE sec, without wildcards is good practice, as the examples in the section 'Parser Basics' in the same document demonstrate.

Comment: @Elise say what? of course you can use `==` in a predicate for determining string equality. I've read the implementation of `NSPredicate`, and more importantly, I've tried it. It works, as do the other comparison operators: `>`, `<`, `<=`, and `>=`.  It's using `compare:options:range:locale:` internally and then just matching the result against the operator.  You can leave out wildcards when doing a `LIKE` comparison, but if you do, it's effectively the same as an "equals" comparison (so perhaps my use of the word "needs" was incorrect).

Comment: @Elise for a concrete example proving that you can use `==` for string equality and that `LIKE` with wildcards is the same thing, try this:  http://pastie.org/2078520  (you can even do things like `==[cd]` for case- and diacritic-insensitive equality)

Comment: I tried it, too, and it didn't work until I changed the operator to LIKE which "proves" my point and I'm too tired to remember when it was and under which circumstances so you win.